# Is it better to use something other than the Time object from @angular/common - TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have user-input data from an html time input. I only need to get the time from the user so I found the Time object from @angular/common here: https://angular.io/api/common/Time

However, this one link seems to be the only documentation on the object and I haven't seen it used anywhere. It also seems a bit weird because you have to define the hours and minutes separately. I was wondering what the best object to use for storing a start and end time in an array (since there can be multiple). The end goal is for the user to fill out their start and end time then display those in two columns into an HTML list.

I'm new to Angular so any advice on what route to take is appreciated.

Comment: That's a type, not an object

Comment: You'd most often simply use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use native [Javascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for simple use cases.

However, if you need more sophisticated methods to manipulate time objects (for example internalization, timezone conversions, methods for duration counting etc.) you should get familiar with dedicated libraries for time and date management and and use time/date classes they provide. See for example

- [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)
- [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)
- [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)